# Can you put multiple content items for a single meta og tag?

Tags: html, meta

If there are multiple content items associated with one og:title, how would you create it?

```
<meta property="og:title" content="cat, dog, mouse" />
```

vs

```
<meta property="og: title" content="cat" />
<meta property="og: title" content="dog" />
<meta property="og: title" content="mouse" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do multiple meta statements on the same property, the browser will take the last statement (this depends on your browser though).

If you want multiple contents for your meta tags, seperate them using `,`.

But, however, you are selecting the meta OpenGraph title, and a title can only have 1 value.

Other OG tags CAN have multiple contents, but a title can't.

Comment: Is there documentation somewhere that mentions titles can't have multiple contents?

Comment: I dont have any documententation but if you do it with title, OpenGraph will just interpret the comma as part of the name itself